# Why these tenses are used in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

Here is the sentence:

> It turns out that she had known him when they were children.

1. Why "turns" and not "turned"? Might the sentence be said when commenting on something like film (can be rewatched so the present simple is used)?
2. Does it mean she had known him by the time when something, that isn't indicated in the sentence, happened?

Comment: Both the tenses (_turns out_ and _had known_) are free choices the speaker made about how they wanted to present the situation. They could equally well have said {It turned out that she knew him when they were children_ or either of the other two combinations.

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is speaking from a point-of-view in the present, which is why "turns out" is in the present tense. Yes, this could be part of the description of a plot in a work of fiction, or it could be part of the current description of a situation with roots in the past. There is no indication which in the sentence without context. "Turned out" could have been used, depending on the context.

"she had known him when they were children." means that they had been in contact of some sort back when they were both children. It doesn't say how old they are now, so we don't know how long ago that is, but presumably some years at least. It doesn't say or imply anything about any particular event happening when they were children.

The sentence implies that there is some connection between "she" and "him" in the present or recent past, known to the speaker. It doesn't say what that is.

"had known" means that she knew him prior to whatever recent event (such as their meeting again, or reading of each other, or whatever)  is being discussed. "Had known" is used rather than "has known" because the knowing took place in the past, and ended some time before (probably many years before) the recent event, whatever it was.

It says that "she had known him". It doesn't say that he knew her, although knowing is often reciprocal.

Without context there isn't much more that can be said about this sentence.

Comment: There is no context, only the sentence alone. I need to know why "had known" is in the sentence instead of "has known". I think there is a past event took place like, as Jack O'Flaherty suggests, she met him and I am telling about the meeting to someone.

Comment: @Vova I edited my answer to respond to your concerns better, and clarify why "had known" and not 'has", and about a possible event.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the use of "she had known him" means she knew him before some other event. For example, you may be telling a story about how she met someone last week, and discovered that she had known him many years ago.

The choice between "turns out" and "turned out" is between two perspectives.
Whichever you choose, it must still be true at the time of saying it.

If you are talking about her perspective at a point in the past, "it turned out" might be more natural. If you are speaking of the fact as news to you or your listener at the present time, "it turns out" might be better.